# How read text file in Android?

Tags: android

I have a text file copied to the Android device. In my app, I want to browse the file, read and process it. The problem is, I am not able to find a method that can reliably get the file path to read the file.

I used the following code to launch the picker:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

try {
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"), FILE_SELECT_CODE);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

}
```

on `onActivityResult`, I tried to get the path and I am observing different behavior on different devices.

**Android 8** device:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
String path = uri.getPath();                //  --> /external_files/info.txt
String fileName = uri.getLastPathSegment(); //  --> info.txt
String absPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() --> /storage/emulated/0
// /storage/emulated/0/info.txt --> I can open the file with this path
```

**Android 7** device:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
String path = uri.getPath();                 // --> /document/primary:info.txt
String fileName = uri.getLastPathSegment();  // --> primary:info.txt
String absPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() --> /storage/emulated/0
// /storage/emulated/0/info.txt --> I can open the file with this path
```

Are there any mechanism where I can get the path to read the file.

Thanks,
GL

Comment: You don't need the path. Call `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` to get an `InputStream`, and read it from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code to get the files content instead of getting the path and read it again:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String s;
while ((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(s);
}
String fileContent = sb.toString();
```

Note that these lines need to be wrapped into a try-catch block and don't forget to close the streams.

Comment: Thanks, i needed that code. Android developer example failed me, but this worked i just neededto add try catch exception.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly from registerForActivityResult without using any permission.

Answer (score -1):

You can read file from this code snippet

```
/**
 * Helper class. Allowing reading data from a file.
 */
public final class FileDataReader {

    /**
     * Read a file line by line. Every line from the file will be a new data emission.
     *
     * @param filename the file being read
     */
    public static Observable<String> readFileByLine(@NonNull final String filename) {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super String> lineSubscriber) {
                InputStream inputStream = FileDataReader.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);

                if (inputStream == null) {
                    lineSubscriber.onError(new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "File not found on classpath: " + filename));
                    return;
                }

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,
                        Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                String line;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        lineSubscriber.onNext(line);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                    // no more lines to read, we can complete our subscriber.
                    lineSubscriber.onCompleted();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    lineSubscriber.onError(ex);
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

For further details check the link below

https://github.com/florina-muntenescu/ReactiveBurgers/blob/master/app/src/main/java/fmuntenescu/reactiveburgers/FileDataReader.java

Answer (score -1):

In Kotlin you should be able to do something like this:

```
val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
val fileContent = inputStream.bufferedReader().use {it.readText()}
```